# Should "Editing Changed" be fired if I return NO from textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString?

Tags: objective-c, delegates, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I am implementing a UITextFieldDelegate's method textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString and returning "NO", as I'm formatting the entered text (as currency) and saving it back to the UITextField's text property.

But I also have the "Editing Changed" event on the text field tied to an IBAction. If I return NO, this action isn't called. It is called when I return YES, but this ends up doubling all the letters in my text field!

1. Is this the correct behaviour? I can't find an authoritative source saying this is the case. If you could answer with a link to Apple's documentation that would be helpful.
2. Is there any way to "manually" fire this event at the end of my textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange... method? (I don't have access to the class my IBAction is defined on from the implementation of my delegate.)

Comment: 1. Well, I tried this and there is no doubling of characters? 2. call the method like this `[self editing changed:yourtextfield]` inside `shouldchangecharactersinrange`?

Comment: According to the **UITextField Protocol Reference**,
**The text field calls this method, i.e., `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString`  whenever the user types a new character in the text field or deletes an existing character.**

Comment: The characters are doubled because inside the delegate method I call stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString: on the textfield contents myself, so I receive the changes the user typed before I re-format the whole thing. If I return YES, Cocoa helpfully adds them in again.

Comment: BlackFlam3 right, and that's happening, the problem is when I return NO, the Editing Changed event isn't fired and another part of my code needs to know something's happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the end of my implementation of textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString (declared in a category on UITextField) I needed to send:

```
[self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

This "manually" fires the event up the responder chain that would otherwise be suppressed by returning NO.